# Sequence $(a_n)$ s.t. $\sum a_n$ converges and $|\{k \in \{0,\dots, n\}: a_{k+1} > a_k\}|/n \to 1$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Find a sequence of real positive numbers $a_n > 0$ s.t. $\sum a_n$ is convergent and s.t.
>
> $\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{| \{k\in \{0,...,n\}: a_{k+1} > a_k\}|}{n} \to 1 \text{ as } n \to \infty\end{eqnarray*}$.
>
> Justify your answer.

The question previously mentions complex series, asks one to prove that an absolutely convergent complex series is convergent and proof the Ratio Test for complex numbers, so that might be intended to be inspiration.

The required condition seems to demand that the tail of the sequence is increasing. So I was thinking of constructing individual increasing sequences that, each dominated by the sequence before: e.g. $x_n = n$, $y_n = n/10$, ... and letting $a_1 = x_1$, $a_2 = y_2$, $a_3 = y_3$ (i.e. letting each 'new sequence' run for one index longer than the previous one). Would this work? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about 1, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) / S1, (1, 2, 3, .., 100) / S2, etc., where Sn = 10^(2n)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am looking for a sequence of positive numbers - are you making a point about why my given example is not convergent? The n^{-1} sounds like a good addition though...

Comment: ok, i think i have settled for an answer now..

Comment: Thanks, that seems right to me!

Answer (score 2):

A much easier way of going about this, I think, is to choose your favorite absolutely convergent decreasing series — $\sum_n\frac1{2^n}$ is a fine example — and then reverse the order on increasingly long subsequences: for instance, have your series be represented as $1+\left(\frac14+\frac12\right)+\left(\frac1{32}+\frac1{16}+\frac18\right)+\left(\frac1{512}+\frac1{256}+\frac1{128}+\frac1{64}\right)+\cdots$.  Now, the number of $k\lt n$ s.t. $a_k\not\lt a_{k+1}$ is $\theta(\sqrt{n})$, so you get the desired behavior.